# User defined function only returning first value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a user defined function that would find the max of three numbers that a user input. When I run the program, it only returns the first value entered.

```
//input
$n1 = $_POST['n1'];
$n2 = $_POST['n2'];
$n3 = $_POST['n3'];

print "Max number entered is: " . find_max($n1, $n2, $n3);
         
//data validation
function find_max($result) {
    if (($n1>$n2)&($n1>$n3)) {
        $result = $n1;
    }
        
    if (($n2>$n1)&($n2>$n3)) {
        $result = $n2;
    }
        
    if (($n3>$n1)&($n3>$n2)) {
        $result = $n3;
    }
        
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Your `find_max` should accept 3 inputs as you pass them like `find_max($n1, $n2, $n3)`.

Comment: `&` should be `&&`. `&` is bitwise AND, `&&` is logical AND.

Comment: `find_max($result)` makes no sense. For one thing, $result is (logically) the _output_ of your function, but you're writing it as if it's the input too. You called the function with 3 values (`find_max($n1, $n2, $n3)`, but your function doesn't accept 3 values! This code will also generate lots of warnings about undefined variables in your find_max function.

Comment: What should your function do if any of the numbers are equal? None of the `if` conditions will succeed in that case.

Comment: That's a good point - in the case where the numbers are equal, $result will be undefined: https://3v4l.org/OiZpr

Answer (score 0):

The defect is fixed by the sort function.
Try following code.

```html
$n1 = $_POST['n1'];
$n2 = $_POST['n2'];
$n3 = $_POST['n3'];

print "Max number entered is: " . find_max([$n1, $n2, $n3]);

function find_max($result) {
    sort($result);
    return $result[count($result) - 1];
}
```

Number 1 argument of the sort function is used to compare items numerically

I will my code helps,